# laravel 7 article argument not passed title in articles view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, laravel-7

I am trying to make a single page of website but i cant passed argument article in view

my controller is:

```
 public function single(Article $article)
    {
        $article->increment('viewCount');
        $comments = $article->comments()->where('approved' , 1)->where('parent_id', 0)->latest()->with(['comments' => function($query) {$query->where('approved' , 1)->latest();}])->get();
        return view('Home.articles.single' , compact('article' , 'comments'));
    }
```

and my view is

```
<div class="subject_head">
    <div class="subject_head--title"><h1 class="title">
        {{$article->title}}
        </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

but i cant passed article title. and my model is

```
 protected $table='articles';
    protected $casts= [
        'images'=>'array'
    ];
    protected $fillable= ['title','slug','description','body','images','tags'];
public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable');
    }
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

i passed this and while used

```
$article->all()
```

this passed all data

[image]
 but when use

```
 $article->title
```

this method is null
and when use

```
dd($article)
```

[image]

Comment: are you sure that ```$article``` object which you are passing to View is not empty?

Comment: i passed this and while used $article->all() this passed all data but when use $article->title  this method is null

Comment: `$article->all()` then you need to loop through it because it becomes an array, or simply for testing just check it like `$article[0]->title`

Comment: when i use loop. this loop give all article but i want use single page article 
i use  $article[0]->title   Trying to get property 'title' of non-object .....article not passed !!!

Comment: when you `dd($article)` inside view what it gives you ?

Comment: all data is null  see this  https://www.mediafire.com/view/cj52pxk1zwgnlwn/sshot-3.png/file

Comment: where have you applied `$article->all()` inside controller ?

Comment: in single controller

Comment: i test all way and use foreach (Article::all() as $article){ and this work...thank you

Comment: `first()` doesn't work either ?

Comment: no...this loop have error and give all data

Answer (score 0):

It has been changed.

Now you need to pass it as array ['name' => 'James']

in your case

```
public function single(Article $article)
{
    $article->increment('viewCount');
    $comments = $article->comments()->where('approved' , 1)->where('parent_id', 0)->latest()->with(['comments' => function($query) {$query->where('approved' , 1)->latest();}])->get();
    return view('Home.articles.single' ,['article'=>$article,'comments'=$comments]));
}
```

Check it here : https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views

Comment: `compact()` method is still working @flakerimi, who told you that it has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

i changed Route of

```
Route::get('/articles/{articleSlug}' , 'ArticleController@single');
Route::get('/series/{courseSlug}' , 'CourseController@single');
```

to

```
Route::get('/articles/{article:Slug}' , 'ArticleController@single');
Route::get('/series/{course:Slug}' , 'CourseController@single');
```

and solved problem.

thank you of all.